# React - Wrapping Parent and Direct Child Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

#### Project Setup

I have a project created with `create-react-app` and have `antd` (Ant Design) installed and configured.

#### Problem

Consider the `<Steps>` component and its `<Steps.Step>` child component from Ant Design.

From the official documentation, we render a multi-step component this way:

```
<Steps>
    <Steps.Step />
    <Steps.Step />
    <Steps.Step />
</Steps>
```

**Note:** I find that wrapping the `<Steps.Step>` components into a single `<div>` will not work. The steps will not be displayed on the web page.

```
<Steps>
    <div class="not-working">
        <Steps.Step />
        <Steps.Step />
        <Steps.Step />
    </div>
</Steps>
```

So the structure must be `<Steps.Step>` components as direct children of `<Steps>`.

Now I want to wrap each of these components into a self-defined React component as follows.

MySteps.js:

```
import "Steps" from "antd";

export default class MySteps extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Steps>{this.props.children}</Steps>
    }
}
```

MyStep.js:

```
import "Steps" from "antd";

export default class MyStep extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Steps.Step></Steps.Step>
    }
}
```

Then rewrite the above code as the following:

```
<MySteps>
    <MyStep />
    <MyStep />
    <MyStep />
</MySteps>
```

However, the result is that, React generates something similar to the following:

```
...
    <Steps>
        <MyStep>
            <Step></Step>
        </MyStep>
    </Steps>
...
```

### Question

What can I do to eliminate the wrapper but at the same time, being able to reuse and wrap a component written by the others without affecting the resulting structure?

Comment: I never tried this, but you might be able to do: export default class MyStep extends Steps.Step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not that you are wrapping in your component but the problem is that you are not passing props to Steps.Step. If you pass all the props to Steps.Step inside MyStep it will work.

```
import "Steps" from "antd";

export default class MyStep extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Steps.Step {...this.props} ></Steps.Step>
    }
}
```

Here is working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-3ytn7

Comment: Well, you're right. Passing `{...this.props}` to `<Steps.Step>` works even if I wrap it into a component. However, is it not possible to avoid React generating those wrapper tags? Can I simply have <Steps><Step /></Steps> in the resulting DOM structure? Can using functions to return components do so?

Answer (score 0):

We can do the same thing in the following way

**Parent Component:**

```
const Component = ({arrow, placement, title, children}) => {

    const LightTooltip = withStyles(theme => ({
        arrow: {
            '&:before': {
                border: '1px solid #1e99fa'
            },
            color: theme.palette.common.white
        },
        tooltip: {
            border: '1px solid #1e99fa',
            borderRadius: '2px',
            fontSize: 12,
        },
    }))(Tooltip)

    return (
        <LightTooltip {...{arrow, placement, title}}>
            {children}
        </LightTooltip>
    )
}

Component.displayName = 'Tooltip'
Component.propTypes = {
}

export default Component
```

**Child Component:**

```
import CustomTooltip from './tooltip'

<CustomTooltip title={'Refresh UI'} placement={'top'} arrow>
    <!-- <IconButton className={classes.refreshPage} onClick={handleManualRefresh}>
        <Icon color="primary" fontSize="medium">refresh</Icon>
    </IconButton> --> children component
</CustomTooltip>
```